# Custom UIView with Lazy Loading scrolls too slow

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, uiview, lazy-loading

So, I currently have a GridView class, which is essentially what it sounds like. It is a subclass of UIView that has a staging area that has a bunch of subviews placed in a grid-like manner. Each cell of the GridView is a custom UIView subclass which calls drawRect.

I implemented lazy loading by following the UITableView pattern.  I only loaded and added the grid cells which were visible (+/- 2 cells on each side).  As the view is scrolled through, I cache cells that are no longer visible in a NSMutableSet and also re-use cells from that Set to build the cells that are now visible.  Everything about that seems to work fine, as I have tested and profiled it, with no memory leaks.

The problem is that scrolling is too slow / jerky.  The faster the user scrolls, the jerkier it is.  Sometimes, if you scroll very fast, it throws a memory warning.  After some debugging work, I found when it starts freezing and jerking, the subviews in the gridview don't get removed, like they should

I also noticed that the scrolling is significantly slower on the iPad 1 vs. the iPad 2.

My questions is, does anyone have any ideas on how to handle this?  Any tricks or optimizations to stop the jerky-ness of the scrolling? Anything would help at this point, as I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Possible slowdown causes : 1) drawRect 2) cacheing during user enabled active interface

choice a) preload, and then present smooth interface, or b) smooth scroll while loading stuff in background, blank areas where load is in progress?

Debugging: have you tried doing NSLog during the process, for example for each cache call, seeing if it is doing a lot of unnecessary work?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  

The drawRect is drawing a rectangle and filling in the background.  In some cases, in another function (not drawRect), it creates another custom UIView (which in turn calls its own drawRect) and adds it in as a subview.  I thought this might be a problem, but after profiling it, the drawRect, doesnt take up too much time.

As for choice a), that wont work because I can have a huge grid, say 1000 x 5, and loading all of those cells can take over 10 seconds

Can you explain choice b) a little bit more?  Im not quite sure I understand.

Comment: The idea being that if you know the space needed for these 1,000 objects, you could make each object and its placeholder gfx be initialized, while the actual loading of content of each object would be dependent on it being visible on the screen. An example could be easytableview By alekseyn. It seems to handle at least hundreds of images with no perceivable glitches. The same logic should be applicable to custom views instead of images, i think.